# How to populate laravel SELECT default value from the database

Tags: php, sql, forms, laravel, laravelcollective

Hi i'm using laravel collective, im trying to load the selected default value from the datbase

```
// $ring->homepage
// holds 0 or 1
{!! Form::select('onhome', [0 => 'Nee', 1 => 'Ja'], null, ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker']) !!}
```

According to the documentation this should work

```
{!! Form::select('onhome', [0 => 'Nee', 1 => 'Ja'], $ring->homepage, ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker']) !!}
```

But it's not working

[image]

It still shows 0 => 'Nee' while it is 1 => 'Ja'

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you opening your form with Form::model as described in the documentation? You need to use form model binding for it to auto populate from the database https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#form-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

The value matches, but the key doesn't. The key has to match with the value in `$ring->homepage`, so you either have to change the keys to 'Ja' and 'Nee', or the value `$ring->homepage` to an integer (0 or 1 in this case).